# Arduino IDE gives elf but does not give hex file

Tags: arduino-ide

Arduino IDE give .elf file but does not generate .hex file.

Show verbose output during: compilation is already selected.

/Users/username/Library/Arduino15/packages/Seeeduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-size -A /var/folders/_6/5v2q3kbs09b7fhtpnxj_zgt00000gn/T/arduino_build_274647/kuzu.ino.elf

Thanks...

Comment: Why do you assume that you should get a hex? Not all boards need a hex.

Comment: Hmmm What will I upload it than without bootloader.

Comment: You are right @Majenko can you please help how to upload it to board? When I try to upload bin.

Comment: Depends what your programmer and the programming program expects.

Answer (score 1):

As I learnt, It does not generate .hex file for some board. If I change board in Arduino IDE it gives .hex file. It is something about CPU. Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Arduino IDE can generate .hex file. The menu choice is Sketch:Export compiled binary.

Two files are created:
your_sketch_name_.ino.standard.hex
your_sketch_name_.ino.with_bootloader.standard.

The second one contains the basic bootloader as well.
Both are stored in the your_sketch_name directory that the IDE compiles and saves in to.

Edit: If you are using a non-AVR uC, I don't know if the command works - or exists even.

Comment: it is not about AVR boards. the command in question contains ARM compiler

Comment: The path contains ARM, is that why you imply it is not about the Arduino IDE?

Comment: @CrossRoads arm boards, work out without the Arduino IDE, are usually programmed with a bin or elf file, not a hex.

Comment: So the question needs clarification then.

Comment: I imply that "Export" will not generate a hex file and a 'with_bootloader' hex if the selected board is from a package that doesn't use hex

Answer (score -1):

As I learned, It does not generate a .hex file for some board. If you change board in Arduino IDE it gives .hex file.

Comment: Repeating an earlier answer word for word is not very helpful. Please add some useful information of your own or delete the answer.